# Turning off the QPython runtime log?

Tags: qpython

I created a Kivy project, developed it into a simple app (besides Kivy widgets, it only imports the socket module), tested it successfully and finally added a shortcut to run the project from the home screen.

How do I get rid of the runtime log that pop ups in the notification area whenever the app is run?

Comment: Id like to know this as well